# How do Spark Executors talk to eachother? FetchFailed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a problem, my executors can't fetch some blocks after shuffling (FetchFailed error) because they aren't reachable.

I would like to try the connectivity myself between workers and I would like to try and create an identical connection (protocol, port) exactly the same as they would naturally do.

I am bit confused, they used **SSH** and the random assigned ports?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what youre trying to do, but it doesn't sound right.

Comment: My executors seem to have problems when talking to "eachother" after a shuffle triggered by a join, I am not sure if it's a connectivity specific issue (ports) or a OOM issue (executor is killed).
To find out if it's a connectivity issue I would like to replicate the connection process (protocol+port) that executors use to talk to eachtoher

Comment: did you check the logs?